# Does process migration in jboss bpm6 work across runtime strategies

Tags: jbpm

I have two run-time strategies deployed, singleton (old processes: version 1) and per process instance (new processes: version 2). I'm trying to migrate processes from version 1 (singleton) to version 2 (per process instance).

While migrating, it updates the process version to 2 but it shows the following error while browsing the task,

```
error: "Unexpected error occurred: org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.SessionNotFoundException:No session found for context 69970"
```

How can I handle this scenario?

quick question: does process migration in `jboss bpm6` work across run-time strategies? or under same strategy only?